# Remove duplicates across multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
         For I = 1 To WS_Count
          ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("A4:Z1000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
         Next I

End Sub
```

I am trying to run the above code to remove duplicates for the A column across multiple Excel sheets, but I get:

> Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Would anyone be able to explain what is wrong with my code, please?

Comment: Does every worksheet have a header in cell A4? You will get this error if the first cell in the range is empty.

Comment: Every worksheet has a header in cell A3, but some are empty besides the header.  I've tried changing A4 to A3 and it still won't work.

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015423/vbas-removeduplicates-does-not-appear-to-work-why), RemoveDuplicates won't work if a cell is blank in the selected range. Try `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("A4:Z" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes`. Note that there must really be some data in all the columns until Z, if not then use the correct ending column.

Comment: @harrymc I just tried OP's code and it works fine, even with empty cells in the range. Michael Nares, can you show the data sheets you've tested this on?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering may be due to *RemoveDuplicates* doesn't support multi-range. Try below if works,

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim col As Range

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For I = 1 To WS_Count
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
        Set rng = ws.Range("A4:Z1000")

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            For Each col In rng.Columns
                If Application.CountA(col) > 1 Then
                    col.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
                End If
            Next col
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```